# Create HTML output from Razor Views on build

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a scenario where I want to build a web page that only consists of static resources, so the server has no other responsibility than serving static files (that way I can deploy it to any server).

Still the pages have the same layout, only the inner content differs.

I have become quite familiar with the Razor syntax and I'm interested if there is any convenient way to build a page with it, only to export the output of pages.

For example I could build it with Razor View Pages run it on my development server visit every site, and save the HTML source from the browser into files, but that is neither automatic nor convenient.

What would be the best way to do this?

P.S. I don't really care if it's a build step generating the output, or something from the Task Runner Explorer, an executable, NodeJS process, etc. I also don't care about the ASP.NET version, or any dependencies it requires during development or build. I plan to build it locally anyway.

Comment: What is the point of using razor if all your content is static?

Comment: Seems like you know the solution, why are you asking this? I mean, crawl your site, or better yet, maintain a list of URLs you want to "build", and save the outputs. It's very simple to do in C#, Node, and even command line with curl.

Comment: @Amit I'm searching for ideas, for example creating an executable which instantiates a ViewEngine and processes the Views directly without a webserver.

Comment: If you're comfortable with node, *and* if it's already a part of your development environment, it's not difficult to do and I'd go with this route. However, this is too broad to be shown in an answer. Limit your question if that's what you're after

Comment: @StephenMuecke Using the same _Layout.cshtml on every view. Using a partial view as a menu, where the selected menu element is the currently visited page. Process the contents of a markdown file on one page by a .net library.